# Error in installing Mod-Security In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mod-security

I use Ubuntu and I want to install ModSecurity. ( I installed LAMP!)
I downlaoded it from github and extracted and I used command:

```
./autogen.sh
```

Result was nothing.
Means Nothing has shown to me. Then...

I used the code :

```
./configure
```

result was:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
configure: looking for Apache module support via DSO through APXS
configure: found APXS at /usr/bin/apxs2
configure: looking for libmodsecurity
configure: error: couldn't find libmodsecurity
```

Help to how can I fix this problem or how can I install Mod-Security (Truly in Ubuntu 18.04 ) and how to configure it...

Comment: *I downlaoded it from github and extracted* What exactly have you downloaded? A zip archive?

Comment: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-apache/archive/master.zip

Comment: There is no `build.sh` in the zip. Do you mean `build.sh` from the [library repository](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity)?

Comment: I changed The problem. Pls read it again. The old problem has fixed. I have new one with configuring it...

Comment: You need to have [libmodsecurity installed](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-apache#compilation) from [the library repository](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity).